# Common Terms Query With Fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application I use a `common terms` query to get documents that match a given input string. I tried different queries and common terms had by far the best results. 
But once the user has a small typo in the string, let's say they accidentally swapped two characters, the result will become much worse. 
In these cases the `match` query has better results.

Is there a way to add fuzziness to a `common terms` query? 
Or should I try to make a `more_like_this` or a `match` query to deliver as good results as the `common_terms` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature request for fuzzy support in `common` queries was rejected some years ago https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3502 AFAICT nothing has changed.

It's not as flexible, but the `match` query supports both `fuzziness` and `cutoff_frequency` which might help you.

Comment: cutoff_frequency doesn't work with fuzziness in elasticsearch 5.2.1